# ng-repeat customize display pattern with different styles

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, using-directives

Consider I have n number of items. First 3 will follow up with different style and item image shot. Next 2 will follow up with different style and image shot. Next 4 will fall under different style and image shot. I wanna do this variation line up in ng-repeat or via custom-directives. Suggest me whats the best way to follow display patterns.

ex:

```
 (*) (*) (*) // Medium Image
  (@)  (@)  // Big Image
(.) (.) (.) (.) // small Image
```

.... This pattern has to repeat for all n number of items,  with pagination.

```
    <li ng-repeat="data in arrivCtrl.content"> // here getting list of objects with item details
    <div class="ItemStyleWith3PerRow" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" >...</div>
    <div class="ItemStyleWith2PerRow" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" >... </div>
    <div class="ItemStyleWith4PerRow" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" >... </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please consider to add some code.

Comment: Oh sure. Added. @Michelem

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be improved, I suggest you specify what are the technologies involved and show us some code.

This said, I am [assuming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc) that this is regarding AngulatJs. As far as what you have server side, I have no idea.

My suggestion to achieve this, is to have your server send to your Angular controller an array with the pattern you want, and then you just use `ng-repeat` to display it.

In fact, this is, afaik, the only decent way of doing it, since `ng-repeat` is used to cycle through data and not to change it.

Something like this should help:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in productsList">
    {{product}}
</div>
```

Also, I recommend some reading:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
- http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

Hope it helps !

Comment: Server: Servlets ( Java ) I don't wanna handle it in server side, as it will an object with huge item collection. Any client side ( angular js) way will help me out.

Comment: What is the server doing ? What items, if any, is the client receiving?

Comment: Server will be busy in loading on each request with more than 100 java ( dto) objects. Per page and item counts will vary on each request following common pattern not advisable there. anyway, I have 100 items in client. Why can't I follow up with display pattern in client (each page in client will follow up with different patterns as above)?

Comment: So, you have 100 random items in your client, and you wish to order them in a certain fashion right?

Comment: First I suggest you add this information to the question (server information, as well as jsfiddle as well). 
Second, how many different row styles will you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ngClass

```
<div ng-class="{ 'ItemStyleWith3PerRow': $index % 3 == 0, 'ItemStyleWith2PerRow': $index % 2 == 0, 'ItemStyleWith4PerRow': $index % 4 == 0 }">...</div>
```

Comment: above mentioned pattern isn't displaying. styles not getting implemented as we expected.